# Wordpress 6.3: WPallimport not taking images from Network Media Library

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, attachments

Setup: Wordpress 6.3 Multisite with Woocommerce

Plugins: [Network Media Library](https://github.com/humanmade/network-media-library) and WPAllimport

Network Media Library is setup to take images from Site 1.
WPAllimport is activated on all multisite sub-sites

While all other images when accessed from the Media library point to xyz.com/sub-site-2/wp-content/uploads/2023 because of the Network Media Library.

When a category/product import is run using wpallimport it looks for the images within xyz.com/sub-site-2/wp-content/uploads/sites

as a result the images don't get attached/linked as category images.

I tried using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function custom_image_import_callback($post_id, $att_id, $filepath, $is_keep_existing_images) {
    // Store the current blog ID
    $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    // Switch to the central media library site
    switch_to_blog(1); // Use the correct site ID here

    // Get the file path using the attachment ID from the central media library site
    $file_path = get_attached_file($att_id);

    if ($file_path) {
        // Prepare the arguments for wp_insert_attachment
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg', // Change as needed based on your image type
            'post_title' => basename($file_path), // Use the filename as the title
            'post_content' => '', // No content needed
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );

        // Insert the attachment
        $imported_image_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path, $post_id);

        if (!is_wp_error($imported_image_id)) {
            // Set image as the featured image for the imported post
            set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $imported_image_id);
        }
    }

    // Switch back to the original site
    restore_current_blog();
}
add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'custom_image_import_callback', 10, 4);
```

When I deactivate Network Media Library and upload images to the subsite media library and then upload categories via wpallimport the category images show, the moment I activate Network Media library the images no longer show.

I'm not sure how to go about sorting/fixing this?